# How to give Regular expression for specific decimal values in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I want regular expression validation for the decimal values which are negative and positive values also.
I tried so many examples with simple regular expression also, but it did not work. so I want full code in c#, not just one line regular expression.

my requirement is like : it can allow for ex:

```
.1
00.1
+.1
+1.0000
-.1
-0.1
-.2311
-23.45
```

So numbers with + symbol values  and - ve symbol values and with out +,- values too.
it should accept starts with .  (i.e point starting ex: .01, .345 etc. )
it should accept only 2 digits before the point symbol. (ex: 00.1,+12.100,-12.1 etc)
it should accept any number of digits after decimal ( point symbol) ex: 90.0956546,23.12233451 etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `decimal.Parse`, `decimal.TryParse` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I tried above one. Its accepting letters also.
I tried the below one.

```
@"^[\+-]?[0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]{1,9})?$";
```

This one is satisfying all the conditions.